# Replacing two characters of field in attribute table using QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, replace

Working in QGIS I have an attribute table containing details of polygons I have digitised, including the two fields, COLUMN_1 and COLUMN_2, each of which is a 4 character Integer that I entered.

However, having entered the last two characters of some entries in COLUMN_2 incorrectly, I now need to correct hundreds of records. Specifically the last two characters of the entry in COLUMN_2, for all COLUMN_1 records = 7777.

I could do this in a Spreadsheet but it's cumbersome and requires too many operations.

Opening the attribute table and starting the Field Calculator, I think the solution lies in the expression...

```
Case When 'COLUMN_1' = 7777 Then regexp_replace(input_string, regex, replacement)
End
```

or in my 'pseudocode' …

```
Case When 'COLUMN_1' = 7777 Then regexp_replace(“COLUMN_2”, right(contents of the field ,2), 99)
End
```

Am I working the right direction and if so how do I write this expression correctly?

The example below illustrates the problem.

[image: From This... To this...]

Comment: Please try `CASE WHEN "COLUMN_1" == '7777' THEN replace(right("COLUMN_2", 2), '99')`

Comment: Thank you Kazuhito, I entered the expression using the correct field names...

CASE WHEN  "BC_NR_TYPE"  == '7777' THEN replace(right("BC_NR_LU_F", 2), '99')
End

and had the errors...

Parser Error:
syntax error, unexpected EQ

Eval Error:
No root node! Parsing failed?

The Attribute Table is in Edit mode. 
In the Field Calculator I selected 'Update existing Field':  BC_NR_LU_F (or COLUMN_2).

Comment: My apologies... the latter part should have been `replace( "COLUMN_2" , right("COLUMN_2",2), '99')`.

Comment: Solved in an hour! Thank you Kazuhito. 

I used your revised code, getting the the same error. 

However, removing a single '=' produced the correct result. 

CASE WHEN "BC_NR_TYPE" = '7777' THEN replace("BC_NR_LU_F" , right("BC_NR_LU_F", 2), '99')
End

Brilliant, you have saved me hours. Many thanks!

Comment: aah! my double apologies. Glad you solved it!

Comment: If this is solved could you add it as an answer and accept the answer so people can readily see the solution?

Comment: @Kazuhito - I think you should consider posting your _comment_ as an **answer** as you helped the original poster come to a working solution ;)

Comment: Thanks @Joseph , I wish I could... Honestly I had been noise at best. Will wait for Peter to post his solution when he has time.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for my late reply, and by way of an answer to my problem...

Selecting only the records '7777's' from the Field (or Column): BC_NR_TYPE and changing the last two digits of Field: BC_NR_LU_F to '99'.

Using the String commands Replace(In Field, Chars from the right, with...) and Right(Chars from the rightmost Char)

Paste the statement below into the  Field Calculator...

Case When 'BC_NR_TYPE' is '7777' Then replace ("BC_NR_LU_F",Right(2) '99')
 End

It is wise to first test your statement by Creating a Virtual Field, in the Calculator before ammending your actual data!